# Angular Observable - Multiple subscriptions don't get captured

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a very simple scenario with an input field and bunch of sections that make API calls based on what is typed in that input field.

Now the input field itself is in a different component, so what I have done is create a behaviorSubject in a service, have a default value and then any time user changes the input field I just call another method within the service that internally calls next on the behaviorSubject.

Then within my different UI sections I subscribe to this behaviorSubject and want to check anytime the value changed make API calls. Note the API endpoints are different for each section but they need to get fired at the same time.

However, I'm unable to get this to work. Here is what I have so far

Code within my service changeService.ts:

```js
valueChangedSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>: new BehaviorSubject({});
constructor() {}
valueHasChanged(updatedValue: any) {
  this.valueChangedSubject.next(updatedValue);
}
```

Code within one component that fires the event:

```js
valueChanged(changedVal: string) {
  this.changeService.valueHasChanged({val: changedval});
}
```

Code within a component that subscribes to the behavior Subject:

```js
this.changeService.valueChangedSubject.subscribe((val:any) => {
   console.log('OK I am here ', val);
});
```

Problem is that the 'Ok I am here' gets printed first time on refresh, but there after any time I call the valueChanged() method it does not trigger the observable.

I know I am missing something related to 'hot observable' here. But what and how to do that? I tried to use share() or publish() but could not get it to work as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A BehaviourSubject is a hot observable. Hot means, even when there are now Subscribers the observables fires new values. I don't see any problem with your code you provided in your question. It looks fine.

Are you sure your `valueChangesSubject` doesn't complete at any time? For example a Subject will complete when it handles an error.

You can check if your Observable completes by using onCompleted callback in subscription.

```js
this.changeService.valueChangedSubject.subscribe(
  next => console.log('OK I am here ', next),
  error => console.error('Error. Observable completes', error),
  () => console.log('Observable completes. No more values will be submitted')
 );
```

Comment: Hi, It does complete. After after i pick a different value from my select input i am calling the valueChanged() method which then also calls the next() in the service but the subscribe is completed so i am not able to capture the new change..

Comment: What i want is that this subscribe should be active and take in new values instead of getting completed. That way any new broadcasts can be retrieved..

Comment: I know what you mean. Your code in your answer looks fine for me. If you just call next() on a BehaviourSubject it will not complete. I think you are doing something different in your code then in your provided example. Can you provide a small Demo on StackBlitz with the same behaviour as you have, so i can have a closer look.

Comment: Thanks very much!! SplitterAlex for two things; asking me to create a StackBlitz, where my sample code worked!! And then looking into the code revealed a v v silly mistake.. I had providers array and the service within each component,. resulting in a new instance everytime.. Removing that fixes the issue

Comment: Link to StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ocaxic?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanother-component%2Fanother-component.component.ts